# (solved)question about proof 3.8 at the book< Measures, Integrals and Martingales> by Rene Schilling?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am self studying this book having a following question.
At [page 18](http://books.google.com/books?id=_OjSIphIrH0C&pg=PA18) the last line of proof 3.8 says" since every 
rectangle I is uniquely determined by its main diagonal" 
then we reach the conclusion that countably many #N . 
How does the author use the diagonal connects to the conclusion? 
Is that diagonal's coordinates?

I am very grateful if any of you help me with this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you add more about the context? also, complete the conclusion of what is to be proved.

Comment: Well, if a set $S$ is countable, then choosing $4$ points of it can be done in countable many ways, i.e. $S^4$ is also countable. And, so is $S^2$.

Comment: Thank you @Berci. I think you are right. And do you mean choosing four points which are distinct? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does the author use the diagonal connects to the conclusion?

Every square with rational endpoints is uniquely determined by the coordinates of the endpoints of the diagonal. So the cardinality of the set of all such squares is less or equal to the cardinality of the set $\mathbb Q^n \times \mathbb Q^n$, which is $\aleph_0$.